# Mozilla Thunderbird: E-Mails from eBay and Kraken are blank

Tags: email, thunderbird

Since month the mails I am getting from eBay.de and Kraken.com are blank, even if I change the message view (original HTML, simple HTML or plain text). Every time the message is blank. And this only happens with eBay.de and Kraken.com (and Fidor.de, if I remember correctly).

I tried the repair function (right-click on inbox-folder -> preferences -> repair). Didn't help!

My mails are different (eBay -> bla1@web.de, Kraken -> bla2@gmail.com).

Someone from Fidor.de said one day, when I had the same problem, it might have to do something with the certificates, but I couldn't figure out, what he meat.

I really need this repaired.

Comment: You should post your question to http://superuser.com/. Stackoverflow is for (some) programming questions.

Comment: Okay, sorry then.